# How do I enhance a closure function in javascript (ES6) and add more logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function:

```
export const field1DisabledIs = expectedValue => ({field1Disabled}) =>
    (expectedValue === false && isEmpty(field1Disabled)) || field1Disabled === expectedValue;
```

So my caller can send a prop `disabled` like so for a component:

```
disabled: field1DisabledIs(true)
```

Now I want to check that if another field (lets call this `field2`) starts with `HS`, then my component should also be disabled.

Something like

```
export const disableField = () => ({field2}) =>
    field1DisabledIs(true) || (!isEmpty(field2) && field2.startsWith("HS"));
```

But it's not working when I call:

```
disabled: disableField()
```

The console on the browser says:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `disabled` of type `function` supplied to `TextInput`, expected `boolean`
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you know that you can use `{ }` to create a multi-line arrow-function? Writing it out on multiple lines and multiple steps might help you understand it a bit better.

Comment: But I think the main issue is that `field1DisabledIs` returns a function, and it looks like you're using it as if it's returning a boolean. It's hard to tell how you should call the function that's being returned, because it depends on what calls the top-level closure. Who calls the function passed to `disabled` ?

Comment: @Evert if I directly call `disabled: field1DisabledIs(true)` I dont' have any error. Not sure how thats working but `disabled: disableField()` isn't

Comment: because field1DisabledIs returns a function, and in your `disableField` implementation you are checking if that function is thruthy. You need to at least call `field1DisableIs` like this: `field1DisableIs(true)(something)`. but it's unclear what the `something` parameter should be, because there's not enough other information.

Comment: In short, it's too hard to tell based on what you've shared so far what you're trying to accomplish. Share a code sample I can run. But at the very least how you invoke `field1DisableIs` is wrong.